# Android Room SUM Query returning null

Tags: android, kotlin, sum, android-room

I am trying to get the SUM of all transaction amounts from my TransactionDatabase but it's always returning null.
Thanks for any help!!

**This is my fragment**

```
val transactionViewModelSum = ViewModelProvider(
            requireActivity(),
            TransactionViewModelFactory(requireActivity().application))
            .get(TransactionViewModel::class.java)

        transactionViewModelSum.getTransactionByDate().observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            totalAmount = it.div(10)
        })

        if(totalAmount == null ) binding.cpbMainExpenses.progress = 15f else binding.cpbMainExpenses.progress = totalAmount!!.toFloat()
```

**My DAO**

```
 @Query("SELECT total(amount) FROM `Transaction`")
    fun getTransactionByDate(): LiveData<Double>
```

**My Repository**

```
fun getTransactionByDate(): LiveData<Double> {
        return transactionDao.getTransactionByDate()
    }
```

**My View Model**

```
private val liveTransactionDate = repository.getTransactionByDate()
...
fun getTransactionByDate(): LiveData<Double> = liveTransactionDate
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Query looks like fine. I think problem in async working of this `transactionViewModelSum.getTransactionByDate().observe()` code.
Try to put `if(totalAmount == null ) binding.cpbMainExpenses.progress = 15f else binding.cpbMainExpenses.progress = totalAmount!!.toFloat()` in observer lambda like bellow:

```
transactionViewModelSum.getTransactionByDate().observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            totalAmount = it.div(10)
            if(totalAmount == null ) binding.cpbMainExpenses.progress = 15f else binding.cpbMainExpenses.progress = totalAmount!!.toFloat()
        })
```

I think that you try to read value of `totalAmount` before `getTransactionByDate` emits a value. If if I'am not right please write me about it in comment.